# How can i make my loop faster its taking way too long

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get the index of the max element after left rotation. Idea is to rotate array a based on the rotate array. So rotate array is looped over and every iteration array a is rotated that many times as the value of the elementin rotate.. lets say if its 2 then rotate array 'a' 2 times. At the same time find the index of max element of rotated array and keep storing it. However the code is taking way too long to execute and the test time out after some time
lets say this is my array

```
const a = [ 1, 2, 4, 3 ]; 
const rotate = [ 2, 1 ];
```

expected output of `getLargestItemIndices` would be array like this

```
[ 0, 1 ]
```

As for first iteration (2 rotations) max value (4) is at index 0 and 2nd iteration max value is at 1

```
let indices =[];
const getMaxValueIndex = (arr)=>{
    const maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
    return arr.indexOf(maxValue);
}

const rotateArray = (a,d)=>{
    while (d) {
      a.push(a.shift());
      d--;
   }
   indices.push(getMaxValueIndex(a));
}

function getLargestItemIndices(a, rotate) {

    for (var index = 0; index < rotate.length; index++) {
        rotateArray(a.slice(), rotate[index]);
    }  
    return indices;
}
```

Comment: Tough to say since we really don't know what your data is or exactly what you are doing with it.

Comment: Just updated to add an example. hope that helps

Comment: Where is `indices` declared?

Comment: And why are you rotating the array to find the index of the largest item? Can you just iterate over the array directly? And why does the largest item have more than one index?

Comment: I have attemped to update question again for better clarity

Comment: This sounds like an interesting problem. I'd really like to know what the real world situation is. (The solution may be something easier than rotation.)

Comment: " So rotate array is looped over and every iteration array a is rotated that many times as the value of the elementin rotate" So you are describing a solution that comes directly from the meanings of the words in the problem that you are trying to solve. To improve the speed of the algorithm, you must find alternative ways to calculate the same results without actually simulating the problem directly. See my answer below for some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i make my loop faster its taking way too long

TL;DR By removing the `rotateArray()` function

Longer explanation:

I suggest breaking this into smaller parts. First, I would write a function to get the index of the largest item in the input array. You can do this easily with a single for loop.

Now once you know the starting index of the largest item. Think about how you can quickly calculate the index of that item after a rotation of `n` positions. Repeat this for each number in the `rotate` array.